# Regex: Remove empty-element tags for xml

Tags: xml, regex

I'd like to replace all self-closed elements to the long syntax (because my web-browser is tripping on them).

Example

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/thing"/>
```

becomes

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/thing"></iframe>
```

I'm using python's flavor of regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of those solutions will accommodate attributes like foo="/>". Try:

```
s:<([\w\-_]+)((?:[^'">]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*)/\s*>:<$1$2></$1>:
```

Exploded to show detail:

```
<
    ([\w\-_]+)    # tag name
    (
        [^'">]*| # "normal" characters, or
        '[^']*'| # single-quoted string, or
        "[^"]*"  # double-quotes string
    )*
    /\s*         # self-closing
>
```

This should always work provided that the markup is valid. (You could rearrange this using lazy quantifiers if you so chose; e.g. '[^']' => '.*?'.)

Comment: `<div class="/>">` isn't valid HTML is it?

Comment: You're looking at attribute *names* in HTML *5*. '/' is permitted between quotes, and '>', while prohibited, is (sadly) commonly seen in production code. Conservative in what you emit, liberal in what you accept.

Answer (score 2):

Use this python regex:

```
(<(\w+)[^<]*?)/>
```

It differs from @Kinopiko's in that it will handle nested elements.

**Explanation of Regex**

1. Find the opening bracket: <
2. Find the word following: (\w+)
3. Find any and all tags between the tag name and its closing bracket *except for another open bracket* to handle nested tags: [^<]*?
4. Find the closing tag: >

Then just replace with this statement:

```
\1></\2>
```

Comment: shouldn't the second < be a > ?

Comment: If you just want to make sure it doesn't swallow another tag then either one is ok.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl,

```
s:(<(\w+)[^>]*?)/>:$1></$2>:
```

will do it.

Comment: I tested it and it trips up on <div><iframe src="http://example.com/thing"/></div> for me.  Does it properly handle that case for you?